# I want to ask a question about elasticity

Tags: probability, derivatives

For example, quantity is given by p(q)=2-ln(3q-4). How to check that it is elastic with given price of 12euros? when I have p(q) and I need q(p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically are asking for the inverse function. You have $p(q)$, you need $q(p)$.

Let's write then:

$$p = 2 - \ln(3q - 4)$$

$$p-2 = -\ln(3q-4)$$

$$\ln(3q-4) = 2-p$$

Now we take the exponential in base $e$, provided the necessary condition:

$$3q - 4 >0$$

So:

$$e^{\ln(3q-4)} = e^{2-p}$$

$$3q - 4 = e^{2-p}$$

From which we get:

$$q = \frac{e^{2-p} + 4}{3}$$

Which means your inverse function is

$$\boxed{q(p) = \frac{e^{2-p} + 4}{3}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much :) I didn't understand  how to make inverse with logarithm

Comment: I have only one question, why 3q-4=e^2-p is q=e^2-p+4, not q=3/e^2-p+4 ?

Comment: @DaumantasGrigas Gosh! Sorry, I made a small mistake! Let me edit it! Thanks!!